# Replace Machine Code- linebreak with php

Tags: php, arrays, preg-replace

currently i'm creating a replace array for several words and character for a wordpress post meta. The goal is to pre-filter or replace words and code.

*My code is like this*

```
$replace_array["*"] = " ";
$replace_array["!."] = "!";
$replace_array["&nbsp;"] = " ";
$replace_array["nbsp;"] = ". ";
$replace_array["."] = ". ";
```

The output is beeing used by a javascript and while i was testing it, i ran into a issue with some machine code. I currently can't figure out why, but some other script is inserting machine code to my wordpress meta, the issue is rare but if it happens it breaks my whole javascript. Bug because normaly is should only have `&nbsp;` or simlar inside the meta and no machine code.

[image: Example of the machine code]

My question is,- is there a way to filter it out with my replace array or do i need make other changes to my php script, because it will not be possible with my current array.

Comment: this may be an encoding issue. check your virtual host configuration, .htaccess files and database configuration. they all must work in single encoding.

Comment: Can you get that text into a decent editor that will allow you to see the HEX code for that character?

Comment: Heximal: i'm running Nginx, the issue is very rare but i will check the Database.
@RiggsFolly, i opened via Winhex and on the part it shows up HEX: 0D0A. i created a image because i'm not sure if i'm right. http://imgur.com/fyU02lf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HEX `0D 0A` is Dos for Newline, Carriage return, nothing very special about that.

Add this to your replace array

```
$replace_array["\n"] = " ";
```

To replace it with a space Or

```
$replace_array["\n"] = '';
```

To replace with nothing

Or if you are on unix maybe this would be better

```
$replace_array["\r\n"] = " ";
```

Or maybe it should be replaced with a `<br>`

Comment: What have you used? And how do you use the `$replace_array` later in your code

Comment: Ah.. i tested it on the wrong part. It IS Working :)    
`$replace_array["\r\n"] = " ";
    $replace_array["\n"] = '';`  Thank you so much!

Comment: Wonderful, great news